# В каком из внутренних классов qt находится текстовый процессор, используемый вQQuickTextEdit и QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qml

В каком из внутренних классов qt находится текстовый процессор, используемый вQQuickTextEdit и QTextEdit ? Читал код QQuickTextEdit, как я понял этот класс отвечает именно за работу с визуальнйо частью, а где сам текстовый процессор?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext.html

Comment: Классы QTextEdit и QQuickTextEdit, фактически, обрабатывают ввод, и определяют "свойства" для текста, но всю работу с самим текстом делигируют QTextDocument, функционал отрисовки QQuickTextEdit реализует через QQuickTextNodeEngine.